# Maximal ideals in $\mathbf{C}[x, y]$ without appealing to the weak nullstellensatz?

Tags: field-theory

I know that the maximal ideals (via the weak nullstellensatz) are precisely 
$(x - a, y - b)$ for $a, b \in \mathbf{C}$. My question is how to show this using the following fact. We can show else that for any ring $k[x,y]$ with $k$ a field, maximal ideals take the form $(p, g)$ with $p$ a prime in $k[x]$, and $g \in k[x,y]$ such that $\overline{g} \in (k[x]/(p))[y]$ is irreducible. Thus a maximal ideal looks like $(x - a, g(x, y))$ with some condition on $g$.

**Question 1:** How do you show that these ideals can be written with $g$ taken to be $y- b$ with $b \in \mathbf{C}$?

**Question 2:** How do you do this kind of computation if instead of $k = \mathbf{C}$, you took $k = \mathbf{R}$? You can't use the nullstellensatz, but you can to use this kind of computation. I guess it boils down to showing (A.) what the prime ideals of $\mathbf{R}[x]$ are, and (B.) what the elements $g$ are that satisfy the condition described above. Can you explain how to do this computation in the case of $\mathbf{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1: $\mathbb{C}[x] / \langle x-a \rangle \simeq \mathbb{C}$, so any monic irreducible in $(\mathbb{C}[x] / \langle x-a \rangle)[y]$ must be $y-b$ for some $b \in \mathbb{C}$ (technically the element would be $y - (b + \langle x-a \rangle)$).

For question 2: The monic irreducibles in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ are $x-a$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, and $x^2 + ax + b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a^2 - 4b < 0$.  In the first case, again $\mathbb{R}[x] / \langle x-a \rangle \simeq \mathbb{R}$, while in the second case, $\mathbb{R}[x] / \langle x^2 + ax + b \rangle \simeq \mathbb{C}$.  Hopefully in both cases you can take it from here.

Comment: How do you prove the statement in Q2 regarding what the monic irreducibles are in $\mathbf{R}[x]$? Assuming it, you get $(x-a, y-b)$, $(x^2 + ax +b, y - c)$?

Comment: (I guess using analysis one can show that odd degree polynomials that are irreducible are linear. What is the corresponding proof for even degree polys?)

Comment: The idea is: any polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.  If that root is real, you're done; otherwise, if $a + bi$ is a root with $b \ne 0$, then $a - bi$ is also a root, so $(x - a - bi) (x - a + bi) = x^2 - 2ax + (a^2+b^2)$ divides the original polynomial.

Comment: Great, thanks it was helpful!

Comment: And actually, you need to be a bit more careful about applying the isomorphisms: you actually get maximal ideals of the form $\langle x-a, y-b \rangle$, $\langle x-a, y^2 + bx + c \rangle$, and $\langle x^2 + ax + b, y - cx - d \rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace $(x-a,g(x,y))=(x-a,g(a,y))$. If $G(y)=g(a,y)$ has degree larger than $1$ it splits in $\mathbb{C}$. Then you can get larger ideals containing it by replacing $G$ by one of its factors of smaller degree.

Comment: 3 questions: 1) you're saying we can repalce g(x,y) with g(a, y) simply because you're identifying $k[x]/(x-a)$ as $k[a]$, so then g needs to be irreducible in $k[a, y]$? (hopefully I understood this correctly). 2) Because a is invertible and because polys of degree > 1 split over $\mathbf{C}$, this means that $g(a,y) = y -b$ for some $b$? 3) Thoughts on Question 2 regarding the field of reals?